# concurrent lock-free singly linked list C++ : does concurrency affect the interface? Do iterators still make sense?

Tags: c++, list, concurrency, stl, containers

I am about to implement a concurrent linked (singly) list on c++ and would like to clarify some points with someone who could have a similar challenge before. Background: initially the list was planned to be a part of skip list, which in turn was a part of in-memory index. When I had started implementing this I would think why not to create a generic solution (in stl-like manner) which could be used aside of skip list. But it seems that the way of how concurrent containers work might differ from single-threaded ones very much. For exapmle, insert and delete operations take iterator as an input argument in std::list, but in case of concurrent  implementation an iterator gets invalid if another thread modifies the list in its vicinity.

It's not a problem if the list is a "layer" of a skip list, since it is sorted in this case, and iterators can be avoided. But I'm curious if anybody tried to implement a generic solution how the issue was resolved.

Another question.. is it worthwhile to make such a container compatible with stl algorithms? It appears that most of them could fail due to concurrency.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/ConcurrentSkipList.h

Comment: Why would an existing iterator become invalid? It still points to a valid node, even if that node's pNext has changed. As for concurrency, you would need to either have a sort of write_lock for the whole list, or one per node (more space required, but less waiting during multiple inserts)

Comment: @paddy Thanks a lot! it's very interesting: it seems they implemented skip list as a solid data structure. It would be interesting to compare performance later on.. it's a challenge to compete with fb :)

Comment: @Rollie Yes, you are right. Iterator contains not a node, but a pointer to it, so all updates are visible. The only case when an iterator gets invalid is deletion of the node which it points on. Thanks for clarification! As per concurrency, a write lock per node looks good, with the only remark, that I'm trying to employ lock-free  approach, so it is not a lock, but rather a guard:)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to create a concurrent linked list container that implements the `std::list` interface, and is completely compatible with stl algorithms.  You just lock the entire thing for each operation.  Naturally, this is not lock-free, and this is not what you want.

The point is that concurrency does not inherently make `std::list` unimplementable -- what  does make it difficult is the particular implementation details, and your lockfree criterion might make this hard.  You should only make this entirely `std::list`-like if it makes sense to do so; since this interface in particular requires that all iterators must remain valid throughout modification of the list, things might get a bit hairy here.  I don't know what lockfree algorithm you're using to implement this, so I can't really comment.

As long as the iterator guarantees are met, even if the container doesn't implement `std::list`, the container will be compatible with stl algorithms, so it sounds like your problem is make sure that those iterator guarantees *are* being met.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, initially I wanted to lock the entire list. It is simlpe, some of the guys [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t732306-concurrent-containers.html) mentions that approach. The only questionable thing is performance. The entire container is locked even if distant elements are accessed, which can be a frequent case if the container is large. Anyway, it is easy to compare the performance, once skip list is implemented (I'm trying to make threading policy a template arg).